# Programatically refresh chrome pages on ubuntu

Tags: linux, google-chrome, script

I'm building a static website. I'd like to write a script that watches a directory and, when a file changes, tells chrome to refresh that page. This is pretty simple with AppleScript, but I'm moving from a mac environment to a linux environment. Is there a way to refresh chrome tabs programmatically in a linux environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091258/chrome-command-line-remote-control-on-linux).  Though setting up might take longer than you hoped for (even needing node.js), it seems [chromix](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix) might float your boat.